# Vba UserForm combobox items don't apear till i click on the userform

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a command button, when i click it, it shows a customized userform which contains a combobox with items taken from a sheet cells. the user is suppose to press the command then the userform appears, he needs to select one item from the list, the item is a sheet name in different workbook, accordingly it will import the data from that sheet. however i am facing a problem:
when the userform appears, i click on the combobox it shows no items, then if i click once on the userform then check the combobox again it shows the items correctly, if i click again on the userform, the combobox items will be doulbled! if i selected an item it works perfectly.
So what i want to achieve is: i want the combobox to show the items directly without clicking on the userform.
the code is this:

In the userform:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()



Dim mlf As Workbook

Dim adad As Long

Dim mada As String

Dim lastRow As Long

Set mlf = ActiveWorkbooklastRow = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For adad = 1 To lastRow

mada = Sheet3.Cells(adad, 1)

With ComboBox1

        .AddItem mada

End With

Next

    End Sub


Private Sub cmdOkay_Click()

 'Verify that an item was selected

If Me.ComboBox1.BoundValue = vbNullString Then

    MsgBox "You did not choose an item!", vbOKOnly

    Exit Sub

Else

    MsgBox "You have selected " & Me.ComboBox1.BoundValue, vbOKOnly

    Sheet3.Cells(1, 2) = Me.ComboBox1.BoundValue


End If

   Unload Me 

End Sub
```

In the CommandButton

```
Dim testbook As Workbook

Set testbook = ThisWorkbook

Set database = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

testbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1:B5").Clear

With UserForm1
.Caption = "Settings of the test"
End With

Dim lo As Integer

For lo = 1 To database.Sheets.Count

     testbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(lo, 1) = database.Worksheets(lo).Name

Next

UserForm1.Show
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are telling it to do that on the click event.

Change

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
```

to

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
```

Once you change this, the combobox issue will also go away.

Comment: you can also use `UserForm_Activate()`, the difference with initialize is : init only fires once, so if you hide the form it won't reset the form and keep data ; on the other hand activate hits each time the form shows, so will reset it each time. Of course, this won't affect the way the form works if you close it with `unload Form` (or Me), but it will if you `Form.hide`.

Comment: PS : the way you have written your code, you need first to `combobox1.clear` before populating it with `userform_activate`

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier: Why would you want to re-init with `_Activate` when the form is shown back. I believe `_Initialize()` is the best way to go about it. Also you do not need `combobox1.clear` in such a case.